# Can someone help me to understand why this is happening?

Tags: html, css, django

## Problem is shown in the link given below

** when i try to hover or press on the navlinks it's not selecting but showing text cursor but by moving a few inches it shows why this is happening is something wrong with the padding or its the chrome ? **

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vbt5geHBPz4)

my html code

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">

  <!-- own css  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/home/style.css' %}">

  <!-- google fonts  -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abyssinica+SIL&family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">TakeAway</a>
    <div class="bx bx-menu" id="menu-bar"></div>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
      <li><a href="#"></a>Home</li>
      


    </ul>
  </header>
  
</body>
```

mycss

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Abyssinica SIL', serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

:root{
  --main-color:rgb(243, 176, 88);
  --text-color:#fff;
  --bg-color:#ff4b24;
  --big-font:5rem;
  --h2-font:2.25rem;
  --p-font:0.9rem;
}
*::selection{
  background:var(--main-color);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

body{
  color: var(--text-color);
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 30px 150px; 
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

.logo{
  color: var(--main-color);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.navbar{
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a{
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar a:hover{
  color: var(--main-color);
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your html, your link text should be **inside** the anchor `<a>` tag as follow:

`<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>`

Comment: oops  i didnt see that...thanks bro...

Answer (score 0):

You need to made some changes on your li element.
How html element looks like :

```
<tagname>Content Here</tagname>
```

If you didn't add content inside the element. then your element is not showing impact of your content.

```
<ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
```